# Kusto query -transform list column's items

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I wrote a query in which I create two tables with two lists using make_list() aggregation function and checking the diff between them using set_difference(list1,list2) function.
the result is one column containing one item - the resulted list, as shown below:

[image]

I'm looking for a query that will transform this list to a column the contain each item in the list as a cell (which means adding a row to that one column containing the list), did not find on the documentation so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator)?